# Jsoup doesn't extract all the expected elements

Tags: java, linux, jsoup

For some reason Jsoup extracts only 2207 elements although there are definitely more of them. For example, the URL of the class `XmlPullParserFactory` isn't read although it's inside an element with the class `jd-linkcol`.

Below is my code:

```
try {
    String url = "https://developer.android.com/reference/classes.html";
    Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(0).get();
    Elements classes = document.getElementsByClass("jd-linkcol");
    BufferedWriter fw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("/tmp/test.txt")));

    System.out.println(classes.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < classes.size(); i++) {
        Elements links = classes.get(i).getElementsByTag("a");
        String classUrl = links.attr("abs:href");

        if (classUrl.contains("XmlPullParserFactory")) {
            System.out.println(classUrl);
        }

        fw.write(classUrl + "\n");
    }
    fw.flush();
    fw.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I'm using Jsoup 1.7.3 which I didn't update since a while.

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem (this requires the HTML you're parsing, for instance -- a minimal version of it, of course, not the more than 2,207 elements). (**In** the question, not just a link to developer.android.com.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The max body size is limited to 1MB by default. With the default settings you are getting only the first 2207 elements from AbsListView to MediaRouter.UserRouteInfo, which comply with the default size of 1MB. To get all elements you can simply change the default settings using:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(0).maxBodySize(1024*1024*10).get();
//for example to set the max body size to 10 MB
```

or

```
//to set it to unlimited size 
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(0).maxBodySize(0).get();
```

Comment: It seems that I've never passed the limit when I used Jsoup, so I always thought that it extracts all the elements per default. Thanks!